# Run SQL script from another directory in Shell script

Tags: shell, unix

in UNIX Shell script I am inside one directory `ex:- cd /usr/was/scr`, then after i connect to the `SQLPLUS` to login into the Database to run the SQL script file **xyz.sql** from different directory location `ex:- /usr/was/abcd`. How to execute the **xyz.sql** after login into the database. Here i the sample code.

```
cd /usr/was/scr
sqlplus -s <schema>/<user>@<tns> << EOF
exec xyz.sql
spool xyz.log
exit;
EOF
```

**xyz.sql** file is in `/usr/was/abcd` directory.

Comment: Doesn't `exec /usr/was/abcd/xyz.sql` work?  Why do you want to `cd` in the first place anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling this from within a script, I would think the safest way would be to specify your paths first:

```
sqlpluspath=/usr/was/scr        #or "${ORACLE_HOME}/bin" or wherever it is if not in $PATH 
spoolfile=/usr/was/scr/xyz.log  #spool file
PATH="${PATH}:$sqlpluspath" \
SQLPATH="${SQLPATH}:/usr/was/abcd" \
sqlplus -s <schema>/<user>@<tns> << EOF
spool $spoolfile
@xyz.sql
exit;
EOF
```

Comment: SQL file is in `/usr/was/abcd` but you mentioned log file is in `/usr/was/scr/xyz.log`. also could not understand 3rd & 4th line.

Comment: @user8487380 Where is the `sqlplus` binary located ? Those lines set environment variables for the program and the shell.  `$PATH` is so you can call the binary from anywhere, and `$SQLPATH` is specifically so that you can refer to any script within the program by calling it's name.  i.e. `@xyz.sql`.  I don't know enough about SQLPLUS to understand what the `exec` directive is supposed to do, but it's well documented that `@` is an alias for `START`.  I'm happy to be corrected

Comment: can i use Alias instead of `cd`. How to go to the path using alias where i have more than 20 sql script files, so that i can not declare one by one.

Comment: @user8487380 It's up to you; If you have 20 script locations, you will need to either: Move them all into one location, reference each script location to set the `$SQLPATH`, or reference the full path of every script file individually.  To me it makes sense to use a combination of organizing scripts together into just a few locations, and adding those locations to the `$SQLPATH` so that you can run them just using their name.

Comment: @user8487380 You said that's what you __were__ doing already ?  In any case, running commands inside a script are much like running them in the shell.  See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/223698)

Comment: where i run the above then i am getting an error `here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOF')`

Comment: @user8487380 have you indented any lines ?  You can often use `<<-'EOF'` instead of `<< EOF` which allows for tab indentation, but I wasn't sure what exact shell you were using, and it looked like you already had the heredoc setup

Comment: I am using subshell (cd /usr/was/scr && <sqlplus connectivity>). so is it wrong or i have to use you mentioned above

Comment: @user8487380 provide a link to ybin or pastebin with a larger section of the script